# Download first picture arrive on site

Tags: php, html

On my site GAME.php page I have many photos in GIF format.

Is it possible that the user who connects to my site on the home page (index.php)  downloads all my GIF images first? Like that when it goes to the page GAME.PHP the images will already download and they will be displayed directly.

If I put the images in a transparent div on the page INDEX.PHP, is that good?
But I find the idea not to be correct.

Comment: Assuming all users go navigate from INDEX.PHP to GAME.PHP, yes you can. This is probably a terrible idea though.

Comment: Can you help me ?

Comment: 1. Why do you want to do this? 2. Will users always visit index.php before game.php? 3. Why are you using GIFs? 4. How many images are we talking about? 5. Why is it a concern that the game.php-page won't necessarily load instantly (you're only moving the loading time to index.php)?

Comment: 1. My gif 1.30mb for one. 2. Index is login page. 3. For animation presentation of wheel game. 4. 10 images.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to the problem. One of the solutions is to include all the images in index.php and don't display them using css visiblility property. And load the game.php content using ajax and make the images visible. Problem with this solution is url's of two pages would be same. This won't be a problem if that is not a concern.

Comment: If I download the images on INDEX.PHP by putting them in an invisible DIV, on GAME.PHP there will be no need to download them a second time?

Comment: What I mean by that is, you include your images in index.php and then load the content of game.php page inside the index.php page when user wants to go to game.php page.